# Updates of async methods are lost in Vue.js components

Tags: vuejs3

I have a component that saves a message to the server on every blur. See full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ob3rhsqp/

My async update method

```
async saveAsync($event) {
  const value = $event.target.value;
  this.message.state = `saving ${value}...`;
  this.message.text = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value + value.length), 1000)
  });
  this.message.state = "saved";
}
```

won't work if the bound prop `message` has changed in the meantime. `message.text` is still updated but `message.state` is not!

```json
[
  {
    "text": "1#ChangedMessage16", // Correct.
    "state": "saving 1#ChangedMessage..." // Wrong, should be "saved".
  },
  {
    "text": "2#Message",
    "state": "saved"
  },
  {
    "text": "3#Message",
    "state": "saved"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.message.state` is updated, but `this.message` refers to the new object, so you won't see the update when old an new state are the same (you can see it when switching to a message with a "saving 1#ChangedMessage..." state).

`this.message.text = await ...` still updates the old message, probably because the whole line is evaluated together, when `this.message.text` still refers to the old message.

Technically, you can think of it like this:

```
this.message.state = `saving ${value}...`;
const target = this.message.state
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)) // <--- this.message changes while waiting
target.text = value + value.length // <--- sets the old object's text
this.message.state = "saved " // <--- sets the new object's state
```

A simple way to avoid it is to store a local copy of message:

```
    async saveAsync($event) {
      const value = $event.target.value;
      const message = this.message // <--- create reference to current message
      message.state = `saving ${value}...`;
      message.text = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value + value.length), 1000)
      });
      message.state = "saved ";
    }
```